# Vertical placement of subfigs adjacent to another subfig

Tags: tables, positioning, subfloats

I have been using LyX, so I am fairly new to manipulating the underlying LaTeX. I have some images that I would like to arrange in a complicated fashion. The format I would like looks like

```
| Fig_A1 |  F   |  
|        |  i   |  
| Fig_A2 |  g_B |  
|        |      |  
|   F i g _ C   |
```

where each Fig_X is a subfloat. I used a tabular layout to force the positioning of the images. However, the output generates two pages: the first is blank, and the second has the figures Fig_A1/2 shifted toward the bottom of the page pushing Fig_C off. Fig_B is fine, though. It looks like this

```
|        |  F   |  
|        |  i   |  
|        |  g_B |
| Fig_A1 |      |  
| Fig_A2 |      |
```

Here is the relevant section from my tex file exported from LyX.

```
%Preamble
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{babel}
% End Preamble

\begin{figure}[H]

\begin{tabular*}{0.9\paperwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cc}
    \subfloat[Figure A]{%
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \includegraphics[width=2in,height=2in]{Fig_A1}\\
            \includegraphics[width=2in,height=2in]{Fig_A2}\\
        \end{tabular}
    } &
    \subfloat[Figure B]{%
        \includegraphics[width=3in,height=4in]{Fig_B}
    }%
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\subfloat[Figure C]{Fig_C}}}\\
\end{tabular*}

\end{figure}
```

Does anyone see a reason why the tabular formatting is not being enforced?

I got the idea for using this type of formatting from [how to put subfigures in several rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/how-to-put-subfigures-in-several-rows)

Comment: Usually when LaTeX posts a blank page before inserting "something", it means that the "something" is too large to fit on a page. Please try to scale all the graphics to one half and see if the error still occurs.

Answer (score 2):

I get a correct result with something like

```
\begin{figure}[p]

\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \subfloat[Figure A]{%
        \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
            \includegraphics[width=2in,height=2in]{Fig_A1}\\
            \includegraphics[width=2in,height=2in]{Fig_A2}\\
        \end{tabular}
    } &
    \subfloat[Figure B]{%
        \includegraphics[width=3in,height=4in]{Fig_B}
    }%
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\subfloat[Figure C]{\includegraphics[width=5in,height=2in]{Fig_C}}}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{figure}
```

Note the `[b]` argument to the inner `tabular`. I've added some dimensions to the last figure, which seemed missing. Note that such a big float should *not* receive the `[H]` specifier, but rather a `[p]` specifier.

Comment: that worked! I guess I need to brush up on the different arguments for figure and tabular.