# How to put 4 figures in an array?

Tags: subfloats

I'd like to  have a possible solution for having this figure in my paper. I want the whole figure to be shaped like this :

```
|                 |    |Figure 2|
|     Figure 1    |    |Figure 3|
|                 |    |figure 4|
```

I already found a first solution in [how to put subfigures in several rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/how-to-put-subfigures-in-several-rows/9585#9585) but the package `tabularx` doesn't seem to be working with the template furnished and named ws-procs9x6 that you can find [there](http://clawar2013.feit.uts.edu.au/downloads/ws-procs9x6_Latex2e.zip).

I'm using the `subfig` package.

Comment: Hi user25273. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please always post complete small documents that show the problem, also "doesn't seem to be working" doesn't give much indication of the error you get. TX is probably not needed for such a layout

```
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\subfloat...1
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\subfloat...2

\subfloat...3

\subfloat...4

\end{minipage}
```

should do something like the layout shown.