# Insert multiple figures in Latex

Tags: floats, subfloats

I need to insert 10 figures (in two columns- side by side) in `LaTeX` that will have one global caption, but also I need to name each `figure` (1a, 1b, 1c, ... ect.). So they will look like:

```
 1a        1b

 1c        1d

 1e        1f

 1g        1h

 1i        1j

Figure 1: plots of....
```

I would really appreciate if you guys can provide any help.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Below is how to insert two figures. Pls adapt this as per your needs. You need `subcaption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{image1}
  \caption{1a}
  \label{fig:sfig1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{image2}
  \caption{1b}
  \label{fig:sfig2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{plots of....}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Refer this for information about another method http://texblog.org/2011/05/24/placing-figures-side-by-side-subfig/

This is also similar to what you are looking for - [how to put subfigures in several rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/how-to-put-subfigures-in-several-rows)

Comment: LaTeX Error: Environment subfigure undefined. What to do now?

Comment: @user1603548 You need the `subcaption` package. I modified the example to reflect this.

Comment: This answer does not explain how to change line and there are some subtleties, e.g., put % after \end{subfigure} etc.

Comment: For some reason inside an itemize which is inside a subsection this goes on a completely random page. Not where it is written in the tex file. :(

Answer (score 35):

Instead of you using two environments-`subfig` and `figure`, you can just use `figure` and `subfloat`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[fig 1]{\includegraphics[width = 3in]{something}} 
\subfloat[fig 2]{\includegraphics[width = 3in]{something}}\\
\subfloat[fig 3]{\includegraphics[width = 3in]{something}}
\subfloat[fig 4]{\includegraphics[width = 3in]{something}} 
\caption{Add your own figures before compiling}
\label{some example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

After every two figures add `\\` or adjust the width so that only two figures fit side by side.

==========================

Please change

```
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
```

to

```
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
```

to see your actual images (instead you will *always* see black boxes.

Comment: @texenthusiast I don't know how to create those fake black boxes so that is the best I could do.

Comment: `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` in preamble will do. Note figure-filenames don't need extensions `something` is fine depending on LaTeX engines executed it will detect which file extension is needed. Hope you might be aware of [mwe](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/mwe.pdf) package that specifically caters to MWE needs.