# How to put several images in one column in LaTex?

Tags: floats

I want to know how to put 3 images in one column in Latex, so that it looks like the following format:

[image]

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: Hello, please could you provide us a MWE ? http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe

Comment: that's essentially just a picture of two images, so if you include two images into latex, that's what you will get?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

You place three images in a column in just the same way as you'd place three letters, just add them in a single paragraph if you want them side by side, or in separate paragraphs if you want them one above the other. Here are three paragraphs with one image in each.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\centering

\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}

\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not absolutely sure what you mean with in one column. Because it looks like just two pictures beneath each other which doesn't necessarily imply that you actually need it column e.g. to display text on the side of the images. 
Although it's quite dirty you could probably just force the pictures on that location with [H]:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics{gull.jpg}
\end{figure}
%do this 3 times
```

Another method would be to make subfigures:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{gull.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{gull.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
    %and so on
\end{figure}
```

By using \textwidth the picture take the full width of the page and should therefore be below each other. The packages are used for subcaptions etc. if you need them.
There's another way to do it with the package float, but i've never done that before. You might want to look at this post: 
[Insert multiple figures in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/insert-multiple-figures-in-latex).

I think this would also work by using minipages.

Comment: I suppose you also need to define the width per subfigure, in addition to the width of the figure itself. E.g. `\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}`