# subfigures in array

Tags: subfloats, multirow

How do I create a figure using subfigures with this alignment?:

```
|figure 1 | figure 3 | figure 4 |
|figure 2 |          |          |
```

Note that I want figure 3 to be in both rows and figure 4 to be in both rows as well. I have seen that the `multirow` package is necessary, however if I use it I am getting a wrong ordering (horizontal instead of vertical). Is there anyway to bypass this?

This is a followup question to this one:
[how to put subfigures in several rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/how-to-put-subfigures-in-several-rows)

Note that the solution is essentially the same, but I am having trouble labelling the order of the subfigures.

EDIT: Code seems to work this way! *I'm using the subfigure package instead.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-5pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-5pt}
\addtolength{\subfigcapskip}{3pt}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\subfigure[car image pair]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{car_example.jpg}
\label{fig:img_pair_1}} & 
\multirow{-4}[2.5]{*}{\subfigure[car image set]{\includegraphics[scale=0.136]{car_total.jpg}    
\label{fig:img_complete_1}}} &
\multirow{-4}[2.5]{*}{\subfigure[animal image set]{\includegraphics[scale=0.136]{aww_total.jpg}
\label{fig:img_complete_2}}} \\
\subfigure[animal image pair]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{aww_example.jpg}
\label{fig:img_pair_2}}\\
\end{tabular}
\vspace{10pt}
\caption[]{Caption}
\label{fig:affinity}
\vspace{-10pt}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `multirow` is not necessary, as can already be seen by answers on the linked question and now also to your question. Next time you ask a question add, please, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify the answers in the linked question accordingly by using either a `minipage` or `tabular` or `tabularx`. I have used `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b][6cm]{0.3\linewidth}
\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{logo}}

\vfill
\subfloat[B]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{logo}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][6cm]{0.3\linewidth}
\subfloat[D]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=6cm]{logo}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][6cm]{0.3\linewidth}
\subfloat[D]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=6cm]{logo}}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Many figures}\label{foo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I change subfloat for subfigures I'm still not getting the layout I want. It's showing A and B vertically, but on a row on top of C and D instead of having all of them in the same "virtual row"

Comment: @Arturo Can you show your code in the question?

Comment: I added the code in the question EDIT section. It's working now, but I had to do some tweaking. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option using [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) and [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[][7.8cm]{%
\begin{subfloatrow}
  \hsize0.54\hsize
  \vbox to 6.35cm{%
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\caption{subfigure-a}}
    {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{smallpicture1}}\vss
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\caption{subfigure-b}}
    {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{smallpicture2}}
  }%
\end{subfloatrow}
\begin{subfloatrow}
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth][]
    {\caption{subfigure-c}}
    {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=6cm]{bigpicture1}}
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth][]
    {\caption{subfigure-d}}
    {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=6cm]{bigpicture2}}
\end{subfloatrow}\hspace*{\columnsep}%
}{\caption{four subfigures}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on the actual size of your figures, you might need to adjust the settings in the first `subfloatrow`.

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative where `varwidth` package and a dummy frame are used, to achieve the desired layout given by the OP.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{varwidth,xcolor}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{varwidth}{0.5\linewidth}  % this is a must
\subfigure[Frame 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im1.png}}\\
\subfigure[Frame 2]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im2.png}}
\end{varwidth}
\begin{varwidth}{0.5\linewidth}  % this is a must
\subfigure[Frame 3]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im1.png}}
\subfigure[Frame 4]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im2.png}}\\
\color{white}
\subfigure[Dummy Frame]{\includegraphics[draft,width=4cm]{dummy}}
\color{black}
\end{varwidth}
\caption{caption.} 
\label{farraypicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Edit: Suggested by Harish Kumar due to depreciated package, here `subcaption` along with `caption` packages are used.

[image]

and this is the code for the image above. (Both `subcaptonbox` command and `subfigure` environments are presented.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{varwidth,xcolor}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=it,textfont={bf,it},labelsep=none}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})~}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}: }

\begin{document}

Use of subfloat command

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{varwidth}{0.33\linewidth}  % this is a must
\subcaptionbox{Frame 1}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im1.png}}
\subcaptionbox{Frame 2}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im2.png}}\\
\end{varwidth}\quad\quad
\begin{varwidth}{0.66\linewidth}  % this is a must
\subcaptionbox{Frame 3}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im3.png}}\quad\quad
\subcaptionbox{Frame 4}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im4.png}}\\
\begin{subfigure}{1in}
\color{white}
\includegraphics[width=1in]{dummy}
\caption*{}
\color{black}
\end{subfigure}
\end{varwidth}
\caption{caption} 
\label{arraypicture}
\end{figure}

Use of subfigure environment

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{varwidth}{0.33\linewidth}  % this is a must
\begin{subfigure}{4cm}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im1.png}
\caption{Frame 1}
\end{subfigure}\\
\begin{subfigure}{4cm}
{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im2.png}}
\caption{Frame 2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{varwidth}\quad\quad
\begin{varwidth}{0.66\linewidth}  % this is a must
\begin{subfigure}{4cm}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im3.png}
\caption{Frame 3}
\end{subfigure}\quad\quad
\begin{subfigure}{4cm}
{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im4.png}}
\caption{Frame 4}
\end{subfigure}\\
\begin{subfigure}{1in}
\color{white}
\includegraphics[width=1in]{dummy}
\caption*{}
\color{black}
\end{subfigure}
\end{varwidth}
\caption{caption} 
\label{arraypicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```