# How to align subfloats in multirows within tabularx

Tags: subfloats, tabularx, multirow

Currently, I have

```
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{figure*}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}ccc@{}}
%
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{a}}
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{b}}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{c}} \\ 
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{d}} 
\end{tabular}
\\
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{e}} 
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{f}} 
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{g}} 
\\
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{h}} 
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{i}} 
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{j}} 

\end{tabularx}

\caption{A selection of the slides made during the user study}\label{slides}
\end{figure*}
```

I expected to see
[image]

but instead, it looks like
[image]

where c and d are misaligned from a and b, and causes the whole row to be taller.

I first started by following [how to put subfigures in several rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/how-to-put-subfigures-in-several-rows/9617#9617), and got the images lined up as I expected.
But the captions labeling was in columns not rows as follows

```
a d g/h
b e i
c f j
```

I tried using multirows, but it had a similar problem

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\multirow{ 2}{*}{\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{a}}}&
\multirow{ 2}{*}{\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{b}} }&
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{c}} \\ 
&&\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{d}} 
\end{tabular}
```

Is there a way to shift up subfloats c and d to match a and b?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For desired align of images c and d you need to add option [b] to nested table, for example:

```
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
```

Beside this your use of `tabularx` is wrong. If you use it, than you also should use its column type `X`. Also the images should be sheduled between columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
%
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
&
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
&
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image}} \\
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image}}
\end{tabular}
\\
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
&
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
&
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
\\
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
&
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
&
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
\end{tabularx}

\caption{A selection of the slides made during the user study}\label{slides}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need no outer `tabular` (even less `tabularx`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image}} \\
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image}}
\end{minipage}

\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}

\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}

\caption{A selection of the slides made during the user study}\label{slides}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The trick is to use a suitable width, namely slightly less than 1/3 of the text width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image}} \\
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image}}
\end{minipage}

\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}

\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}

\caption{A selection of the slides made during the user study}\label{slides}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're not tied to `subfig` for specific reasons of a document class not compatible with `caption`, I recommend using `caption` together with `subcaption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\subcaptionbox{caption}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{caption}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{caption}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image}}\\[1ex]
\subcaptionbox{caption}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image}}
\end{minipage}

\medskip

\subcaptionbox{caption}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{caption}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{caption}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}

\medskip

\subcaptionbox{caption}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{caption}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{caption}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}

\caption{A selection of the slides made during the user study}\label{slides}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]