# Latex: How to control the space between the images in one figure

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I am writing a latex file and I have six pictures to place in one figure with three on each line. How I can do that? and how I can increase (or decrease) the space between these pictures?

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
  subfigure[\label{1a}]\includegraphics*width=0.45\textwidth]{Pic1}}
 \subfigure[\label{1b}]\includegraphics*width=0.45\textwidth]{Pic2}}         
    \subfigure[\label{1c}]\includegraphics*width=0.45\textwidth]{Pic3}} 
     \subfigure[\label{1d}]{\includegraphics*width=0.45\textwidth]{Pic4}}
\subfigure[\label{1d}]{\includegraphics*width=0.45\textwidth]{Pic5}}
\subfigure[\label{1d}]{\includegraphics*width=0.45\textwidth]{Pic6}}
      \caption{{}
  \label{Fig1}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I want to put the three first Pictures(Pic1,2,3) in one line and the other three (Pic 4,5,6) in another line.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  This is a fairly common type of question and you should be able to find several questions with answers on this site already.  If they don't solve your problem, please post some specific code (as a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) to show what you have tried, and explain what you need to fix.

Comment: Thank you for the code.  You should add it to the question, via the edit button, rather than placing it the comments.  I have now done this for you.  However, the code is only a snippet not a complete minimal document that can be compiled on its own.

Comment: Have look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9584/15925

Comment: you need to extend your code sniped to complete but small document with `\documentclass{...}` on beginning, with only necessary package in preamble and ending with `\end{document}`, which reproduce your problem. It seems, that you use obsolete packages and your images are now 2 in the first row, 1 in the second and 3 in the last. Note, empty line in code means that you start new paragraph/row with images.

Comment: Sorry, this happened by mistake. @Zarko

Comment: @Gadoora2t, see my general answer below, maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You have more issues with your code snippet:

- strange (at least to me unknown) syntax
- sum of images widths in one row is bigger than text width
- use of probably obsolete package for sub figures

Since you not provide complete small document (Minimal Working Example: MWE), solution below  is based on guessing, i.e. actually provide generic solution ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[\label{1a}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Pic1}}\hfill
\subfloat[\label{1b}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Pic2}}\hfill
\subfloat[\label{1c}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Pic3}}

\subfloat[\label{1d}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Pic4}}\hfill
\subfloat[\label{1d}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Pic5}}\hfill
\subfloat[\label{1d}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Pic6}}
      \caption{My famous collection of images \dots}
  \label{Fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Gadoora2t, if answer help, than you can upvote and accept them (by clicking on up-pen and check-mark at top left side of answer).
 This is  the usual way how to say thank you in this site  to express your thankfulness :).